# UrlFetchApp returns different response from what I see in browser

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, booking.com-api

I'm trying to scrape hotel prices from Booking.com, and now getting a weird response body that is different from what I am seeing on my browser in private mode.

When you run the Google Script below then you'll get '2178' JPY as a result, while just hitting the same url on the address bar in private mode, you'll see '2420' JPY.

```js
function myfunction() {
  
  var destid = '2658464'; 
  var year = '2018';
  var checkin_month = '12';
  var checkin_monthday = '20';
  var checkout_month = '12';
  var checkout_monthday = '21';
  
  var url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?checkin_year=' + year + '&checkin_month=' 
  + checkin_month + '&checkin_monthday=' + checkin_monthday + '&checkout_year=' + year + '&checkout_month=' + checkout_month + '&checkout_monthday=' + checkout_monthday 
    + '&no_rooms=１&group_adults=1&group_children=0&dest_id=' + destid + '&dest_type=hotel&selected_currency=JPY';
  
  Logger.log(url);
  
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  // Retrieve 'div' that contains the top search result
  var res = Parser.data(html).from("<span class=\"sr-hotel__name").to("class=\"sr_item sr_item_new sr_item_default").build().trim();
  var price;
  
  if ( res.indexOf('sold out on') != -1 ) { //when sold out on specified date
    Logger.log( 'SOLD OUT' );
  } else if ( res.indexOf('Dormitory') != -1 && res.indexOf( destid ) != -1 ){ //if its dormitory room and contains specified destId

    // retrieve price value in <b> tag
    price = Parser.data(res).from("<b>\n¥").to("</b>").build().trim().replace(new RegExp('[^0-9]', 'g'), '');
    Logger.log('Price: ' + price);

  } else {
    Logger.log( 'SOLD OUT' );
  }
  
}
```

Basically, Booking.com shows discounted price according to loyalty level (called Genius Booker) of the user currently logging in. My script somehow retrieves discounted price, even though giving any credentials.

In most cases this my scripts works fine enough to show the original price, but for some hotels, it returns discounted price for Genius bookers.

How come do you think does this happen, and is there any way to force scripts always to return the original price?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi @Jacque Thank you for your attention! I just modified my whole question to provide code that reproduce the issue. Would love you to take a look and appreciate any help or guess.